# unable to display data from an ajax request in a thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the code below and for some reason I am unable to replace the `{photo}` and `{name}` in the `var thumbnail` with some values from my database. If I try to console log the values I can see them, but on the frontend I just get an `{name}` and and the default image icon, like the replace function doesn't work at all. I cannot see what is the problem here, can someone explain?

```
var p = {};

var searchInput = $("#category").tagsinput('items');

var thumbnail = '<div class="col-lg-12">\
 <div class="thumbnail">\
   <img src="{photo}" alt="img">\
     <div class="caption">\
       <h4><a href="">{name}</h4>\
   </div>\
 </div>\
</div>';

$("#submit-search").on("click",function () {
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(searchInput.itemsArray);
console.log(myJsonString);

$.ajax({
  "url":"search.php",
  "method":"POST",
  "cache":false,
  "data":{data:myJsonString}
}).done(function (sData) {



   p = JSON.parse(sData);
// console.log(p[0].name);

for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {

  var rTemplate = thumbnail.replace("{{photo}}", p[i].photo).replace("{{name}}", p[i].name);
console.log(p[i].photo);
  $(".rContainer").append(rTemplate);
}


});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `{var}` as your template placeholder but you're trying to replace them using `{{var}}` that's why it's not working, change your replace with this:

```
thumbnail.replace("{photo}", p[i].photo).replace("{name}", p[i].name);
```